# Why does it keep freezing

Tags: c

I have tried switching the defines to consts but it doesn't seem to work either

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TIMES 5/9
#define MINUS 32
int main()
{
    int temp_fahr = 0;
    printf("Enter the temperature in fahrenheit\n");
    scanf("%d\n",temp_fahr);
    printf("The temperature in celcious is: %.3f\n",(temp_fahr-MINUS)*TIMES);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you enable compiler warnings?

Comment: Try `scanf("%d\n", &temp_fahr);`

Comment: Your calculation is **integer arithmetic**, which is then passed to `printf` to satisfy a `double` argument expected.

Comment: ... so it needs to be `(double)(temp_fahr-MINUS)*TIMES`

Comment: Among other things, the value of `TIMES` is 0. If you write `(double)(temp_fahr-MINUS)*TIMES`, it will work, but not for the reason you might expect. That never computes the value of `5.0/9.0` (approximately 0.555); rather, it's equivalent to `((double)(temp_fahr-32)*5)/9`. The `5` is promoted to floating-point for the multiplication, then the `9` is promoted to floating-point for the division. Use `#define TIMES (5.0/9.0)`; using floating-point constants avoids truncating integer division, and the parentheses force it to  be evaluated as a single expression.

Comment: By the by, was that a freeze you were getting or a crash? Those are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the line

```
scanf("%d\n",temp_fahr);
```

As the compiler warnings will tell you, it expects an input of type `int *` but receives an integer instead. So, it tries to write into the address `temp_fahr` points to which causes a segmentation fault.

Second, if you fix it by supplying a pointer to `temp_fahr`, `scanf` keeps waiting for the newline which gets trimmed from standard input, so it gets stuck there. So, the correct line is

```
scanf("%d",&temp_fahr);
```

You'll also notice that the `%f`format expects an argument of type `double` and receives an integer instead, so you'll want to cast the result to double at some point before passing it to `printf`.